# Click a imageview popup a view showing the original image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, tableview, afnetworking

I have loaded several images to a table view. The image has been resized, and I want that when user tap on the imageview, it pops up a view showing the original image size, and when user click again anywhere, the view disappears and get back to the tableview. The code that loads the image like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    SearchCell *cell = (SearchCell *)[atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    cell.name.text = [[self.brands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    __weak SearchCell *weakCell = cell; 
    [cell.leftImageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://s-57130.gotocdn.com/%@", [[self.brands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"pic"]]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"app_icon.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

        CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;
        CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;

        CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(70, 70);
        CGSize newSize = targetSize;
        CGFloat scaleFactor = targetSize.width / imageWidth;
        newSize.height = imageHeight * scaleFactor;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
        UIImage *small = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        weakCell.imageView.image = small;

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    }];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to resize the image manually. If you set the `imageView` `contentMode` property to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, it will automatically scale to fit the size of the image view.

As for scaling on tap, check out [UIImageViewModeScaleAspect](https://github.com/VivienCormier/UIImageViewModeScaleAspect).